# Does Playwright Chromium Headless Browser have different behaviour in Local vs. Virtual Private Server?

Tags: python, instagram-api, playwright

I want to run Headless Chromium using Playwright (using python libraries) on a virtual private server running on Ubuntu for some Instagram scraping work

For that particular operation, I am required to access this URL - `'https://www.instagram.com/p/{shortcode}/?__a=1&__d=dis'`

`{shortcode}` can be any ID from any IG post permalink.

Example: https://www.instagram.com/p/Cf1096juPL5/ would become -> https://www.instagram.com/p/Cf1096juPL5/?__a=1&__d=dis

This URL contains the data which the operation requires for scraping.

---

I am accessing the relevant URL using Playwright in my local system using Windows 10 and it works as expected. It returns the HTML document consisting of JSON formatted data (which is extracted and processed as required).

The same process does not work in my server on Digital Ocean which uses Ubuntu 22.04. The browser redirects to the Login page of Instagram when the URL is requested.

*[Note: On no test scenarios are authentication states preserved. Tests are performed without cookies.]*

The following is the code I use to access the relevant URL to scrape data:

```
def __run(playwright: Playwright, url: str, credentials: dict) -> dict:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=True)
    context, page = None, None


    context = browser.new_context()
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()

    page.goto(url)
   
    content = page.inner_text('pre')
    return (content)
```

Is this behaviour justified when using Playwright or is this related to something else?